# Can I read other than the first sheet with the Read Delimited Spreadsheet.vi function in LabVIEW?

Tags: excel, csv, labview

I am using `Read Delimited Spreadsheet.vi` in LabVIEW and need to read data from other than the first sheet. How do I tell LabVIEW that want to use other than the first sheet?

Comment: Do you have a file that you can succesfully using Read Delimited Spreadsheet but you think you're only getting the first sheet? In that case what you have is a CSV (or other delimited text) file, even if it has a .xls or .xlsx extension, and as [Mateusz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71472844/24447) says there are no multiple sheets in a CSV file. If the CSV was created by doing Save As from Excel then only the active sheet gets saved to the CSV.

Answer (score 1):

CSV files are plain text files and there are no multiple sheets inside.
Sheets are present within Excel files, but this function "Read Delimiter Spreadsheet" does not work with these.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately LabVIEW still doesn't have built-in support for reading Excel files as far as I know, although it can write them with the `Save to Measurement File` express VI.

There are [third-party toolkits](https://www.ni.com/en-gb/search.html?pg=1&ps=10&sb=%2Brelevancy&sn=catnav:sup.dwl.tnt&q=excel) available for reading Excel files in LabVIEW, or you might be able to [use some Python code](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019WHGSA2&l=en-GB) with [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to read a Excel file (.xls or .xlsx) and not a CSV file (as suggested by Mateusz the CSV file doesn't have sheets).

Anyway, in LabVIEW you can read, write, manipulate and do any other operations on Excel files by using ActiveX. It is verbose but you can use it as any other LabVIEW library.
Look [this post](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/labview-excel-with-activex/td-p/3770585) or the built-in examples in your LabVIEW environment

Comment: Excel's .NET interface is more stable (harder to crash), with similar capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you can use Excel to read a spreadsheet. Alternately, you can use LibreOffice.
[LibreOffice to LV library](https://lavag.org/topic/19265-cr-libreoffice-simple-lv-interface/)